# RegEx: get content between two strings, only for records containing a given value

Tags: regex, powershell

In Powershell, given the following string/record:

```
1758,Y9 - Science 2018-19,ACTIVE,Science YR 9 18-19,mydomain.org_classroomd11edec9@group.calendar.google.com
```

I am using a regular expression to extract content between `mydomain.org_classroom` and `@group.calendar.google.com`:

```
(?<=mydomain.org_classroom)(.*)(?=@group.calendar.google.com)
```

The above will extract correctly: `11edec9`

I need to add another condition: string must contain "ACTIVE" as shown.

How can I add this condition?

Comment: You may add it to the lookbehind: `(?<=ACTIVE.*mydomain.org_classroom)`. I'd also recommend using `.*?` instead of `.*` and escape dots that you want to match as literal chars.

Comment: Wiktor, this throws an error, see here https://regex101.com/r/DCEHPJ/1

Comment: Certainly it will in PCRE. Are you really using Powershell? Then try it in Powershell. It uses .NET regex. Regex101 does not support .NET patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this mate**

```
(?<=ACTIVE.*)(?<=mydomain.org_classroom)(.*)(?=@group.calendar.google.com)
```

> What was missing in your regex.

- `(?<=ACTIVE.*)` - Positive look behind. It will match a string which contains ACTIVE.

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DACTIVE.*%29%28%3F%3C%3Dmydomain.org_classroom%29%28.*%29%28%3F%3D%40group.calendar.google.com%29&i=1758%2CY9%20-%20Science%202018-19%2CACTIVE%2CScience%20YR%209%2018-19%2Cmydomain.org_classroomd11edec9%40group.calendar.google.com%0D%0A%0D%0A1758%2CY9%20-%20Science%202018-19%2CScience%20YR%209%2018-19%2Cmydomain.org_classroomd11edec9%40group.calendar.google.com)

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: @Riccardo you can upvote if it helped :p anyways happy to help :)